# Android: Database INSERT triggers exception "getWritableDatabase called recursively"

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, sqliteopenhelper

Whenever the asynchonous task tries to insert data into the SQLite database I run into the following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively

The data is produced by a service that runs separate asynchonous tasks to download, convert and finally to insert the data. I am not sure if the **context** objects I am passing are correct. Please **note the comments I added** to the source code. In the following I added the relevant classes and functions. Please leave a comment if you need futher information.

```
public class CustomServiceHelper {

    // This method gets called by the activities.
    public static void loadData(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    } 
}
```

...

```
public class CustomService extends Service {

    private void startStoringTask(Users users) {
        // Passing the context of the service.
        mStoringTask = new StoringTask(this);
        Object[] params = { users };
        mStoringTask.execute(params);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class UsersProvider extends ContentProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // Not sure if getContext() is correct.
        mDatabase = new CustomDatabase(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case URI_CODE_USERS:
            long id = mDatabase.insertUsers(values);
            // TODO: Not sure about the return value.
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class CustomDatabase {

    public class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(TABLE_USERS_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    private CustomSQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper = null;

    public CustomDatabase(Context context) {
        // The context is passed in by the UsersProvider.
        mDatabaseHelper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public long insertUsers(ContentValues contentValues) {
        return mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(
            CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_USERS, null, contentValues);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class StoringTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Boolean> {

    private Context mContext = null;
    public StoringTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Users users = (Users)params[0];
        return storeUser(users);
    }

    private boolean storeUsers(Users users) {
        if (users == null) return false;
        // Not sure if calling getContentResolver on this context is correct.
        ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
        Iterator<User> iterator = users.iterator();
        do {
            User user = iterator.next();
            storeUser(contentResolver, user);
        }
        while (iterator.hasNext());
        return true;
    }

    private void storeUser(ContentResolver contentResolver, User user) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(1);
        cv.put(CustomDatabase.Contract.COLUMN_NAME, user.name);
        contentResolver.insert(UsersProvider.Contract.URI_USERS, cv);
    }
}
```

When I run the application in *Debug* mode I end up in the framework class `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the `finally` block of the `runWorker()` method.

---

**Edit:**
Here is the full exception stack trace.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:81)
com.test.users.database.CustomDatabase.insertUsers(CustomDatabase.java:125)
com.test.users.database.CustomDatabase$CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.insertTestData(CustomDatabase.java:85)
com.test.users.database.CustomDatabase$CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(CustomDatabase.java:60)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
com.test.users.database.CustomDatabase.insertUsers(CustomDatabase.java:125)
com.test.users.contentprovider.UsersProvider.insert(UsersProvider.java:51)
android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:174)
android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:587)
com.test.users.tasks.StoringTask.storeFeature(StoringTask.java:82)
com.test.users.tasks.StoringTask.storeResponse(StoringTask.java:58)
com.test.users.tasks.StoringTask.doInBackground(StoringTask.java:32)
com.test.users.tasks.StoringTask.doInBackground(StoringTask.java:1)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

I did not mention the method `CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.insertTestData()` which invokes `getWritableDatabase()`. I call the method `insertTestData()` in `CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()`. The crash happens everytime whenever the application has not created a database yet. To summarize, hawaii.five-0 was totally right!

Comment: add here class of SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively

So this kind of `Exception` is usually thown when you use `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` in `onCreate` or `onUpgrade` methods of **SQLiteOpenHelper**.

Comment: I read about the same problem in other questions. However, I very scepticale about the **context** I use. What's your option on those?

Comment: so in onUpgrade method you should first call db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME); and then call again onCreate(db); it's some little cheat.